# Can i pass a name + a var through POST PHP

Tags: php, html

Im writing a web page that updates scores on a database and i was wondering if i could pass a name + a variable through the form POST method e.g. (homeScore $i) where $i is the for loop index. the user can input a number to change the score and i will update the score in that database.
heres what i got in the first for loop

```
<input type="number" name="awayScore <?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $arrayScores[$i]['awayScore']; ?>">
```

and when i want to pull the POST in another for loop

```
$arrayScores[$j]['homeScore'] = $_POST["homeScore $j"];
```

so far i keep getting an error saying "Notice: Undefined index: homeScore 0" all the way to homeScore 6

Comment: Still not sure what are you asking about, but PHP recognizes nested params as a multidimensional array, so you can use i.e. `<input name='foo[bar][baz]>'` and access it as `$_POST['foo']['bar']['baz']` so you can also use the name like `awayScore[1]`, `awayScore[2]` etc. and just in PHP iterate `$_POST['awayScore']`

Comment: side note don't use spaces in argument names, also as commented before it is better to use array notation like `foo[123]` then string containing numbers like `foo123`

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
<input type="number" name="awayScore <?php echo $i; ?>" value="<?php echo $arrayScores[$i]['awayScore']; ?>">
```

With

```
$val = isset($_POST['awayScore'][$i]) ? $_POST['awayScore'][$i] : "";
<input type="number" name="awayScore[<?php echo $i; ?>]" value="<?php echo val; ?>">
```

Don't use space character within the field name, you may used `[]` notation, the `isset` line is to prevent you from getting error when there's no value in exist in the `$_POST['awayScore']` array.

Comment: Thank you @JaxLee for rewriting my comment, that was so helpful ;>

Comment: Welcome @biesior Indeed your comment point out most of the mistake that beginner will make or some how ignore. By providing an example more related to their posted  code, will help them even further instead of letting them figure out themself. guideline has been given and is up to them to take up or not. ;) Cheers mate.

Comment: I appreciate your will of help, however, the main purpose of the Stack is (if possible) to add the most generic solutions, so it can be also re-used by other (future) users. Of course, I could write the answer myself with this code, but I prefer to get more details, to avoid any doubts before answering. Nvm, the only thing I would like to ask you is adding some more generic details about using arrays as $_GET/$_POST arguments, preferably with some samples, not just posting very strict code as an answer for very specific issue.

Comment: Hi, so that isset method didnt work out unfortunately :(. Im getting the error "Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of an expression (you can use "null !== expression" instead)" but thanks for the help anyways. I think im just going to try a complete different method anyways because i cant spend all day on code that might not work :/. Once again tho, thanks yous for all the help :D